# V3 and V2 results of youtube api is not matches

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am working on YouTube API. I doing analysis on V2 and V3. At present I tried to retrieve the HD videos. The output is not matching when I am using same query.

Using V3

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q=football+-soccer&start-index=1&max-results=10&videoDefinition=high&key={Developer key}

Using V2

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer&orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2&hd&alt=jsonc

Where V3 is stable? or should I continue with v2 for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I've been integrating youtube v3 for a while now and notice it has less flexibility as v2. For example, when doing a video search, in order to get the video's statistics I have to submit another query.

Comment: No user you are wrong you can use v2 parameters inside v3. Its update version, I too have the same feel after exploring v2 and switch back to v3. At that time feel it very difficult. But the thing is both are same. You can use same parameters. The issue also solved which i have posted. I got same track of video result by parsing query string in both v2 and v3. To get better a idea read the api v3 frequently.